# React native navigation parameter not working with Switch navigator

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm using react native navigation and redux in my code.
Below is my navigation structure

```
const MainTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home,
    Tenants,
    WorkOrders: {
      screen: WorkOrders,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Work Orders',
        headerTitle: 'Work Orders'
      }
    }
}, {
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
      const { routeName } = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];
      return {
        headerTitle: routeName
      };
  }
});

const MainStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    MainTabNavigator
}, {
  defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
      return {
        headerLeft: (
          <Icon
            style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}
            onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
            name="md-menu"
            size={30}
          />
        )
      };
    }
});

const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Menu: {
    screen: MainStackNavigator
  }
});

const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Login: { screen: Login },
  Main: { screen: AppDrawerNavigator }
});
```

Then, I have an action file where I navigate from the Login to the Main pages.

```
async
...
console.debug(response.data);  // Here the console shows value 10
NavigationService.navigate('Main', { userID: response.data });
```

In the HomeScreen page I tried to see the parameter value:

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
const userID = navigation.getParam('userID', '0');
console.debug(userID); // HERE THE VALUE IS 0, BUT SHOULD BE 10
```

What I am doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass params with a [`SwitchNavigator`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html), it's clearly intended in the doc:

> By default, it does not handle back actions and it resets routes to
>   their default state when you switch away.

If you really need to share objects between screens, you should use [redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) rather than `react-navigation`.